# Git:User->Server->hook post rec->push to Live Server "Fatal: empty ident <push@blabla.(none)) not allowed" when push despite having identity set

Tags: git, permissions, githooks, git-config

I'm getting this error:

The architecture and workflow is like this:

1)developer pushes to remote repo(dev server) through ssh-> 
2)Dev server has a post receive hook that invoques a bash script on a live server through ssh->

```
#!/bin/bash
while read oldrev newrev refname
do


    branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)

    # Use this if-sentence to only update live server if branch is the wanted branch, e.g. master or stable
    if [[ "desarrollo" == "$branch" ]]; then
            # Fetch this branch from live-server
            ssh push@mpdvsweb-test.jusbaires.gov.ar '/bin/gitmirror'
    fi
done
```

3)Live server executes the script that fetches data from the dev server->

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/penal_test_git
git fetch git-repo
git merge -m 'Overwriting live server' -s recursive -X theirs git-repo/desarrollo
```

4)I get the the following error on the machines of every developer(the git config --global is set for us but it's not working, I also tried setting it for the repository and it doesn't work either)

[image]

what could be failing?

`git config --local -l`   returns the user.name and the user.email  and  `git config -l` returns the user.name and user.email twice , maybe one is the local and the other the global. On another developer machine the global is the only one set and is not working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I changed three things and it worked. First I deleted the local repo identity and then I redefined the global config(I don't know if this made the difference cause I already had the global config configured correctly).
Then, I had to change  the bash on my live server to fetch --all, otherwise without that flag it gives conflicts merging if someone edit the files on the live server directly cause when the hook of the dev server executes it won't let the merge happen, in this way everything gets overriden:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /var/www/penal_test_git

git fetch --all
git reset --hard git-repo/desarrollo
```

Finally, the files had a permision of root user instead of www-data cause another developer changed it and it didn't let override the file with the fetch. This is part of another error, but it helped to make it work.